# Maintaining reference to feature layer (rather than its name string) throughout Python script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, parallel-processing

When creating a Layer in arcpy, the syntax uses a string to denote the layer name, as shown in the [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) sample script:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("city", "citiesLyr")

print(type("citiesLyr")) # => string
```

As far as Python is concerned, "citiesLyr" is just a string (right?). Can I instead define the feature layer as a variable?

This is an attempt to simplify a more complicated scenario. I'm trying to use the feature layer in a script which involves multiprocessing, loops and functions, and I'm finding that the reference to the layer is being lost, and all I'm left with is a string called "citiesLyr". How can I keep the reference to the feature layer throughout my script?

The example below doesn't do anything - the point is to test how to gain access to the feature layer from within the function, which has been called within the multiprocessing environment:

```
import multiprocessing, arcpy

def doCity(lyr):
    #How to get access to the cities layer from this function?
    print(lyr)
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr) # <= this fails because the layer is just a string
    print(desc.SpatialReference)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Create a feature layer from the cities
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\city", "citiesLyr")

    #Create a list, so we can use the multiprocessing function
    citiesList = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        citiesList.append("citiesLyr")

    # Create a pool class and run the jobs
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(doCity, citiesList)

    # Synchronize the main process with the job processes to ensure proper cleanup.
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

(The cities list itself is also pointless - it's only there to use  multiprocessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the blocking point you are currently encountering can be illustrated in this short bit of code:

```
import arcpy

def doCity(lyr):
    print(lyr.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\city", "citiesLyr")
    citiesLyrObject = arcpy.mapping.Layer("citiesLyr")

    doCity(citiesLyrObject)
```

You will see that what I am passing into the doCity function is now a layer object rather than a layer name string.

I found how to do this in [an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/53459/115) to [Can MakeFeatureLayer Object be Passed into ExportReport Function Layer Parameter?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53453/can-makefeaturelayer-object-be-passed-into-exportreport-function-layer-parameter).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've implemented that change, which has thrown light on a different error. I've rewritten the question to focus on that instead.

Comment: @StephenLead Procedurally, I would be more inclined to rollback your last edit, and to ask about "Unpickleable" in a new question. I say this because the changed question invalidates this answer whereas I think it was highly relevant to the original: "I'm finding that the reference to the layer is being lost, and all I'm left with is a string called "citiesLyr". How can I keep the reference to the feature layer throughout my script?".

Comment: The original could then be made a "signpost" duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53453/can-makefeaturelayer-object-be-passed-into-exportreport-function-layer-parameter and be of increased rather than lost value to the site.

Comment: New question on multiprocessing posted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/114260/3112