# arcpy with multiprocessing throws "UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'geoprocessing Layer object'> objects"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, parallel-processing

I'm attempting to speed up a process which is currently running synchronously, by using the python multiprocessing module.

I'm having trouble sending a feature layer to a function which is called by multiprocessing, as demonstrated in this simple script:

```
import multiprocessing, arcpy

def doProcess(lyr):
    print(lyr.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Create an array of feature layers
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb"
    featureLayers = []
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","All","World")
    for fc in fcs:
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc + "_lyr")
        lyrName = fc + "_lyr"
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, lyrName)
        featureLayers.append(arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrName))

    #This works when not using multiprocessing:
    for featureLayer in featureLayers:
        doProcess(featureLayer)

    #This fails with "UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'geoprocessing Layer object'> objects"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(doProcess, featureLayers)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When iterating over the array manually, rather than using multiprocessing, the function has access to the feature layer. But when using multiprocessing, this error message is shown:

> UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle type 'geoprocessing Layer object'
>   objects

What is the correct syntax/approach to handle a feature layer within the multiprocessing environment? I based the above script on the example on the Esri blog [Multiprocessing with ArcGIS](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/26/distributed-processing-with-arcgis-part-1/)

Comment: There is a GeoNet thread worth looking at on this one: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/31027 where Jason Scheirer says "many objects in arcpy/arcgisscripting are not pickleable, so sending them directly across the wire in multiprocessing will not work. There are workarounds, however."

Comment: Maybe you should build an ad-hoc object using python built-in type to make sure it would be "pickleable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the time to look into this. I don't fully understand the "unpickleable" error message, but a workaround is to pass only strings into the multiprocessor. Something like this:

```
import multiprocessing, arcpy, os

def doProcess(fClass):
    #This function doesn't do anything, it's just to show that accessing arcpy methods is possible
    print("in do process function for " + fClass)
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb"
    arcpy.Delete_management(fClass + "_lyr")
    lyrName = fClass + "_lyr"
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fClass, lyrName)
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyrName)
    print("Finished " + desc.Name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Create an array of feature class names
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb"
    fClasses = []
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","All","World")
    for fc in fcs:
        fClasses.append(fc)

    #Multiprocessing approach
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(doProcess, fClasses)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

(Interestingly, this script takes a lot longer to complete when I use the multiprocessing approach, compared to just running:

```
for fClass in fClasses:
    doProcess(fClass)
```

Presumably there's a lot more overhead in setting up the environments for each thread. Hopefully in a more complicated scenario involving long geoprocessing tasks, the payoff would be faster overall completion of all tasks.)